# How Laravel deletes old log files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm using `Laravel 5.4`. In my `config/app.php` file, the log storage option is set to `daily`. So the framework will create a daily log file like 'laravel-2019-03-11.log'. Also, the old log files will be deleted automatically as per default value or as per the value of `log_max_files` in the `config/app.php` file.

My question is where the unlink code is written (I tried to find it in the vendor folder but no luck)? Also, is there any way where I can override this default logic. What I want is, instead of removing these old log files, move it to another folder like `log_backup` or something.

Comment: Run a cron that does this instead of changing anything in `vendor`. If you really want to make a change you will need to wire up your own logging.

Comment: The unlink code is in the RotatingFileHander.php (https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php). It's a bad idea to change anything in the vendor folder since it can be overwritten whenever you run a composer install/update, but it will give you an idea of where to start to extend or create your own.

Comment: @aynber Thanks for providing information about the file. It really helped me. But is there any way by which I can override this default functionality?

Comment: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/tree/master/src/Monolog/Handler

Comment: If you can upgrade to Laravel 5.6 (or higher), the whole logging system was revamped and it would be a matter of adding an additional "backup" log channel to the stack in `config/logging.php`. This would by far be the cleanest solution

Answer (score 3):

The old files are deleted by `Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler::rotate`.

I know you're using 5.4, but if upgrading to 5.6 (or higher) is an option then you can take advantage of the new logging features. All you would have to do is add a new `backup` logging channel to `config/logging.php` and include it in `stack`. This would by far be the cleanest solution.

For example, to keep a backup of all `critical` or higher logs:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily', 'backup'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ],
    'backup' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/backup.log'),
        'level' => 'critical',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a separate command to move the log files periodically with cron job.

Here is an example.

move files to another folder.

```
public function moveLogs(){

  File::move( app()->storagePath().'your file name', $your/new/path )

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am supposed to do the same still I want to know about how the default log behavior works. I've read laravel documentation but that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.4 your log file has automatically deleted because may be you already have 5 log files for daily basis in your log directory & log_max_size in laravel 5.4 have default value of 5 thats why your logs have been deleted automatically.